# How Can I Do Calculation in Bid And Ask Price which I am getting From Binance Websocket Java Script

Tags: javascript, binance

I am Getting The Live Prices Of Btc Future Ask and Bid And Btc Spot Ask And Bid I want To Subtract Btc Spot Ask form Btc Future Bid i.e Spread. I converted them to Float As Well but In console i get NaN

```js
let btcspotws = new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@bookTicker');
let btcspotbidElement = document.getElementById('btcspot-bid');
let btcspotaskElement = document.getElementById('btcspot-ask');

var btcspotask
var btcfut1ask
btcspotws.onmessage = (event) => {
    //console.log(event.data);

    let btcspotobject = JSON.parse(event.data);

    let btcspotbid = parseFloat(btcspotobject.b).toFixed(2);
    btcspotbidElement.innerText = btcspotbid;

    let btcspotask = parseFloat(btcspotobject.a).toFixed(2);
    btcspotaskElement.innerText = btcspotask;
};

let btcfut1ws = new WebSocket('wss://dstream.binance.com/stream?streams=btcusd_220325@bookTicker');
let btcfut1bidElement = document.getElementById('btcfut1-bid');
let btcfut1askElement = document.getElementById('btcfut1-ask');

btcfut1ws.onmessage = (event) => {
    //console.log(event.data);

    let btcfut1object = JSON.parse(event.data);

    let btcfut1bid = parseFloat(btcfut1object.data.b).toFixed(2);
    btcfut1bidElement.innerText = btcfut1bid;

    let btcfut1ask = parseFloat(btcfut1object.data.a).toFixed(2);
    btcfut1askElement.innerText = btcfut1ask;
    
};

console.log(btcspotaskElement - btcfut1bidElement)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Live Crypto Price</title>

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <table style="width:70%">
    <tr>
      <th>BTC</th>
      <th>Ask</th>
      <th>Bid</th>
      <th>Spread</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>BTC/USDT</b></td>
      <td id="btcspot-ask">Loading...</td>
      <td id="btcspot-bid">Loading...</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>BTC USD 25 Mar</b></td>
      <td id="btcfut1-ask">Loading...</td>
      <td id="btcfut1-bid">Loading...</td>
      <td id="btc-spread">Loading...</td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, I made some adjustments to your snippet:

```js
let btcspotbidElement = document.getElementById('btcspot-bid');
let btcspotaskElement = document.getElementById('btcspot-ask');
let btcfut1bidElement = document.getElementById('btcfut1-bid');
let btcfut1askElement = document.getElementById('btcfut1-ask');
let btcspreadElement = document.getElementById('btc-spread');

let btcspotask;
let btcspotbid;
let btcfut1ask;
let btcfut1bid;

let btcspotws = new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@bookTicker');
btcspotws.onmessage = (event) => {
    let btcspotobject = JSON.parse(event.data);
    btcspotbid = parseFloat(btcspotobject.b).toFixed(2);
    btcspotbidElement.innerText = btcspotbid;
    btcspotask = parseFloat(btcspotobject.a).toFixed(2);
    btcspotaskElement.innerText = btcspotask;
};

let btcfut1ws = new WebSocket('wss://dstream.binance.com/stream?streams=btcusd_220325@bookTicker');
btcfut1ws.onmessage = (event) => {
    let btcfut1object = JSON.parse(event.data);
    btcfut1bid = parseFloat(btcfut1object.data.b).toFixed(2);
    btcfut1bidElement.innerText = btcfut1bid;
    btcfut1ask = parseFloat(btcfut1object.data.a).toFixed(2);
    btcfut1askElement.innerText = btcfut1ask;

    // Here you can display the spread:
    btcspreadElement.innerText = parseFloat(btcspotask-btcfut1bid).toFixed(2);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Live Crypto Price</title>

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <table style="width:70%">
    <tr>
      <th>BTC</th>
      <th>Ask</th>
      <th>Bid</th>
      <th>Spread</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>BTC/USDT</b></td>
      <td id="btcspot-ask">Loading...</td>
      <td id="btcspot-bid">Loading...</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>BTC USD 25 Mar</b></td>
      <td id="btcfut1-ask">Loading...</td>
      <td id="btcfut1-bid">Loading...</td>
      <td id="btc-spread">Loading...</td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bro You Are The Best You solved the problem i was facing from 2 days